# how to export database from openLCA to brighteway2

Tags: brightway

I have some ecoinvent database in openLCA form,like this

[image]

want to try to use brightway2

How to export database from openLCA to brighteway2?

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Cliff Notes ^ - You need to post the code you have tried, any error messages, and it must be in text form and not an image of the code if you would like actual help.  You listed a picture of the file names, that tells us nothing about them other than the name.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the [converter](https://www.openlca.org/format-converter/) provided by openLCA to convert your database to Ecospold2.

I would also look into this [library](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway-olca), which allows brightway to communicate with OpenLCA, Although it seems like it has not received updates in a long time, it might still work.

Check this [project](https://github.com/cyrillefrancois/openlca2bw) out if all fails, it seems promising but I have never tried it.